# Why Postgres array takes place after comparision operator while comparing?

Tags: postgresql, operators

Here i got noticed that in Postgres string array comparisons we should give array after comparison operator. 
For Example:

```
SELECT campaign_products 
FROM contacts 
WHERE 'PMP' LIKE ANY(campaign_products) limit 10;

SELECT campaign_products 
FROM contacts 
WHERE 'as' = ANY(campaign_products);
```

But when i use like below it giving a syntax error:

```
SELECT campaign_products 
from contacts 
where ANY(campaign_products) = 'as';

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ANY"
LINE 1: SELECT campaign_products from contacts where ANY(campaign_pr...
```

Can some one explain me this and let me know if there is any way to give array left to comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

It's the SQL standard.

In ISO/IEC 9075-2 (2003), Foundation, it is defined as follows:

> **8.8 <quantified comparison predicate>**
>
> **Format**
>
> ```
> <quantified comparison predicate> ::=
>     <row value predicand> <quantified comparison predicate part 2>
>
> <quantified comparison predicate part 2> ::=
>     <comp op> <quantifier> <table subquery>
>
> <quantifier> ::=
>     <all>
>   | <some>
>
> <all> ::= ALL
>
> <some> ::=
>     SOME
>   | ANY
> ```

So it's a question you'd have to take up with the SQL standard.

But seriously, why do you need `ANY =`? It should not be a problem to switch the sides so that the comparison is syntactically correct.

Think of `= ANY` or `= SOME` as operators where the left side is a value and the right side is a collection of values. PostgreSQL extends the SQL standard syntax by allowing arrays on the right hand side.

Comment: I just want to know what happening and what is the difference string comparison and string array comparison. For example: select id from contacts where status = 'lead' limit 1; and select id from contacts where 'lead' = ANY(statuses) limit 1; are giving result to me but select id from contacts where ANY(statuses) = 'lead' limit 1;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ANY"
LINE 1: select id from contacts where ANY(statuses) = 'lead' limit 1...

Comment: It is just syntactically incorrect. I have edited the answer, maybe it will become clearer. `<comp op>` must be right before `<quantifier>` in the syntax diagram. The `ANY` does not belong to the `<table subquery>`.